# Mapping elements from one dataframe to another based on matching column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

Reference_DF:

```
root_cause_level3   root_cause_level2   root_cause_level1
NA                  NA                  NA
Natural Disaster    Natural Disaster    Natural Disaster
Other               Other               Other
Communications      Misunderstood       Long Message
```

Actual_DF:

```
incident_id        root_cause_level3       root_cause_level2   root_cause_level1
XXXXXXXX-1         Communications       
XXXXXXXX-2         NA       
XXXXXXXX-3         NA       
XXXXXXXX-4         Other        
XXXXXXXX-1         Natural Disaster
```

My goal is to map **from Reference DF to Actual DF** the level2 and level1 root causes. I want to map it based on matching level3 root causes. I don't know how to do that, any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Expected output:

```
incident_id        root_cause_level3       root_cause_level2   root_cause_level1
XXXXXXXX-1         Communications          Misunderstood       Long Message
XXXXXXXX-2         NA                      NA                  NA
XXXXXXXX-3         NA                      NA                  NA       
XXXXXXXX-4         Other                   Other               Other        
XXXXXXXX-1         Natural Disaster        Natural Disaster    Natural Disaster
```

Comment: What is your expected output dataframe from this data?

Comment: you have two `root_cause_level2` columns in your `Actual_DF`. is one of those supposed to be `root_cause_level3`?

Comment: @ScottBoston, thanks for the feedback, I added the expected output

Comment: @wpercy oops, yeah that was a typo, thanks for the catch

Comment: Use `merge` with `left_on` and `right_on` parameters.

Comment: If you know it's a duplicate guys, please close it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) like this:

```
new_df = pandas.merge(actual_df, reference_df, on='root_cause_level3', how='left')
```

a cleaner way could be to do something like:

```
new_df = pandas.merge(actual_df[['incident_id','root_cause_level3']], reference_df, on='root_cause_level3', how='left')
```

then you don't get duplicated column names in the `new_df`

Comment: Blessed, thank you!